# Tkinter window keeps expanding when I drag it to the top even though I limited the max and min window size

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a tkinter window that won't expand when the window is dragged to the top. At first I used the win.Resizable(0,0), but this completely disabled the maximize button on the top right of the window, and the window would not center itself anymore when I dragged the window to the top. I then found that I could simply limit the maximum size of the window with win.maxsize(width=1270, height=725) , but when I would maximize the window on my laptop screen, the window would slightly expand which would mess with the positions of the widgets on the window. On my larger monitor, this isn't a problem and the window centers itself like how I want it to when the maximize button is pressed, or when the window is dragged to the top without getting larger. The code I have here has a blue background that is only set to a specific length so if the window expands, the rest of the window will be the default light grey color. My monitor is set to 150% size for the scaling of items, and is set to a resolution of 1920, 1200.

```
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()  # creates the tkinter window
win.geometry("1270x725+0+0")
canvas1 = Canvas(win, width=1400, height=725, bg='#00538f')

canvas1.place(relx=-.1, rely=0)  # places the canvas a little left of the actual window so that the entire window
canvas1.create_rectangle(0, 0, 1400, 72.5, fill='#005FB9', outline='#005EB9')
canvas1.create_rectangle(0, 72.5, 1400, 150.4, fill='#005FC8', outline='#005FC9')
canvas1.create_rectangle(0, 150.4, 1400, 217.5, fill='#005FD7', outline='#005FD9')
canvas1.create_rectangle(0, 217.5, 1400, 290, fill='#005FE6', outline='#005FE9')
canvas1.create_rectangle(0, 290, 1400, 362.5, fill='#005FF5', outline='#005FF9')
canvas1.create_rectangle(0, 362.5, 1400, 435, fill='#005FF4', outline='#005FF9')
canvas1.create_rectangle(0, 435, 1400, 507.5, fill='#005FE3', outline='#005FE9')
canvas1.create_rectangle(0, 507.5, 1400, 580, fill='#005FD2', outline='#005FD9')
canvas1.create_rectangle(0, 580, 1400, 652.5, fill='#005FC1', outline='#005FC9')
canvas1.create_rectangle(0, 652.5, 1400, 725, fill='#005FB0', outline='#005FB9')
win.minsize(width=1270, height=725)
win.maxsize(width=1270, height=725)  # prevents the window from being resized


win.mainloop()
```

I added two snapshots to show what I mean. The first has a white boarder which happens when I expand the window on my laptop monitor and the second is how it looks when I slightly move the window in any direction as long as the window doesn't try to maximize again.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You may just have to use smaller maxsize values for the smaller monitor. Why do you not want the window to fill the screen when dragged to the top, but still want it maximized? You should be able to turn this off in your system settings; on my Ubuntu, this setting is called tiling.

Comment: The only reason is because the widgets move out of place when the window size changes, and even that slight change that I show is enough to mess up the widgets.

Comment: Wow, I only had to reduce the max by 5 units.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Putting widgets into a window so that they expand nicely is a _lot_ easier than making the window not resize in a certain way; maybe you should edit your question to ask about your widget resize problems, instead of how to make the window not resize. Widget resize problems, again, are _really_ easy to fix, and fixing them will make your window look better too :-)!

Comment: The only reason I am hesitating to do that is because I have to many widgets and I'm scared that I would have to start over in terms of placing everything on the window again, but I might ultimately have to do that.

Comment: Depending on your widget setup, you can use loops to create some of them. By the way, in cases where there are lots of widgets in the same parent, I suggest using `grid()` instead of `pack()`. But yes, it is better to start over and make your window function better in terms of resizing (even though it may take some work) then to try to make the window resize in unusual ways because of a compromised widget setup. Happy and successful coding! I am open to any further questions you may have on the subject, and I will answer them when I can :-)!

Comment: I am using .place(relx=? ,rely=? )which I think is just like grid() but I'm not sure. All the resizing solutions I have found so far use the .pack() method so I have no idea how I would do that when my widgets don't really use rows or columns, they are simply placed in places that seem to be best for them.

Comment: No, grid is different. `.place()` uses pixels as the units; you have to calculate the distance yourself. `.grid()` uses rows and columns, with varying **weights**, which control how much the widgets expand relative to other widgets. With `.grid()`, tkinter does all the pixel calculation itself, thus making the widgets expand well regardless of the window size. The details on how to use `.grid()` are a little complicated to explain in comments, but there are plenty of examples on SO and online. I strongly recommend not to use `.place()`, because it isn't flexible for different window sizes.

Comment: Wish I had known that before, but thanks for the info.